# Find the integral solution of a given equation while minimizing the integral sum of solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

Suppose we are given a linear equation in $n$ dimensions:

$$Ax+By+Cz=S\,\,\,\,\,\, (n\text{ is }3)$$

with constraints on $x$, $y$ and $z$ as :

$$0\le x\le p,$$

$$ 0\le y\le q,$$

$$ 0\le z\le r.$$

We have to find the integral solution of this equation such that $x+y+z$ is **minimum**.

For example:

$$ 678 x+ 123 y+ 12 z=996$$

where

$$ 0\le x,$$

$$ 0\le y,$$

$$ 0\le z.$$

The solution which **minimizes** $x+y+z$ are $(1,2,6)$ and $(0,8,1)$.

What general methods can be applied to solve such a problem where we have constraint on all dimensions that they are greater than zero ?

Comment: If A,B,C is even S is odd, no integral solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of problems that can be solved by the [Simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) combined by the [Cutting plane method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method).

In general is hard to solve efficiently.

---

The feasible set (the set of points that satisfies the restrictions) lie on the portion of the plane $P=\{Ax+By+Cz=S\}$ that is inside the parallelogram defined by the inequalities. The intersection is a convex polygon. I think at most it is a hexagon but most of the time it has smaller number of sides.

The objective function $x+y+z$ gets smaller when you move in the direction of the vector $(-1,-1,-1)$. You can project this vector onto the plane $P$. That tells you in what direction to move inside the feasible set.

But you first need to find a feasible solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @VidorVistrom Elaborating can take a one half-year course. You are asking  for a general approach to solving an integer linear programming problem. If the family of problems is more specific then maybe a tailored approach is possible.

Comment: Yeah I understand the complexity, but can you show an example, maybe the one mentioned in the question? I have to make a program that works on this concept. The situation is, out of given list of +ve integers(678, 123 and 12 as mentioned above) I want to find the minimum frequency that adds up.(x,y,z denotes the frequency of each respectively)

Answer (score 0):

This first stage is to look for, and remove, any common factor.

For your example, $gcd=3$ giving $226x+41y+4z=332$

With $n=3$, find the variable with the second smallest range of values, and isolate it to the LHS.
In your example,
$$41y=332-226x-4z$$

Now substitute the numerical values for the variable with the smallest range of values, then solve the resulting equations.
**Note, start with small values and stop at the first solution in each group.**

In this case, $x$.

When $x=0$, we have $41y=106-4z$ and a few trials give $z=6$, so $y=2$.

When $x=1$, we have $41y=332-4z$ and a few trials give $z=1$, so $y=8$. If you were to continue to find more solutions, that must be larger (eg $z=42,y=4$).

When $n>3$, its much the same idea, just working down the substitutions until you have a set of two-variable equations.

Please let me know if you need elaboration.

Comment: Thats hit and trial... Even if I make a system that runs on this mechanism, it wont be scalable. Imagine 100 dimensions! Anyways.. Thanx for the try :)

Comment: Sorry, I failed to realise you were considering such gigantic values for $n$. I’ve never nested loops more than twenty deep, but if you should wish to construct such an example equation, I’ll take it on as a design challenge. I’ve upvoted this question, as it’s far more interesting than I first thought!